# using ng-show with array length after web service callout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to show an alert box if the size of an array is 0. The array is populated by a web service call and is thus 0 when the controller loads. When the promise is resolved the array is populated, but the alert stays on the page.

How can I update the view state of alert after the promise has completed? Here is what I have so far:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="!items.length">You have no items.</div>

profile.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', 
  function($scope, $http, $window) {

    $http.get('/api/getItems').success(function(data) {
      $scope.items = data;
    });
  }
]);
```

here is the response:

```
[{"test" : "data"}]
```

When I try to use the apply function I get an inprogress error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

$http.get('/api/getItems').success(function(data) {
  $scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.items = data;
  });
});
```

I ended up just hardcoding the items array when the controller loads... the div still shows up.

Comment: The $.get belongs to jQuery?

Comment: You could: `ng-hide='items.length>0'`

Comment: why would that be different?

Comment: So I just created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/x7QTQJ0bVqkKhN3dEAjT) using `$timeout` rather than `$http.get` and it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have code that isn't being shown here, there is no need for `$timeout()` or `$scope.$apply()`.

After the `$http.get()` promise is resolved, the `$scope.items` value is populated and Angular runs a `$digest` cycle to update the view which will show/hide the alert based on the latest value of the expression (`items.length`).

[This plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3cPpBesxOiN9GH2utU18?p=preview) demonstrates different types of results and the view updates correctly.  You can change the `.json` files to produce empty arrays and you will see the alert correctly show/hide.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're using $.get from jQuery. Try using $http instead for the promises to be resolved and ui updated.

```
profile.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function($scope, $http, $window) {
$http.get('/api/getItems')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data;

    });
});
```

Comment: i changed it to http... except now i get an inprogress error on apply Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Comment: My mistake, not $.http but $http.get(). Did you catch that?

Comment: I also removed the $scope.$apply, i don't think you'll need it because the watchers should be aware of this change

Answer (score 0):

use the .then because is an asynchronous call, like this:

```
profile.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function($scope, $http, $window) {
$http.get('/api/getItems').then(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data;
    });
});
```